# automake and custom rpath

Tags: linker, autotools, automake, libtool, rpath

I have to ship a third-party library with an application. Because I don't want to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by hand or require any wrapper script I want automake to set a custom `rpath`. Unfortunately `libtool` has its own `-rpath` option and adding `-Wl,-rpath,/foo/bar` to `LDFLAGS` only results in

```
g++: unrecognized option '-rpath'
```

because `libtool` seems to get confused with the command line options. The same happens with the alternative form `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/foo/bar`.

Is there any way to specify a custom rpath without libtool interference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `libtool` has its own `-rpath` option.  Any reason you don't want to use it?

```
% libtool link g++ foo.cc -o foo -rpath /somewhere
libtool: link: g++ foo.cc -o foo  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/somewhere
% readelf -d foo | grep RPATH
0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/somewhere]
```

None of the examples in the Automake or Libtool manuals use `-Wl` to specify `-rpath`.

Comment: Thanks, specifying `-rpath` (or `-R`) in `_LDFLAGS` works. Still seems weird that libtool only accepts a random mix of standard and own (linker) flags.

Comment: Can I specify relative `rpath`? Libtool fails with error saying: `error: only absolute run-paths are allowed`

Comment: I mean, I'd like to use '$$ORIGIN/libs`