# How do I set up my C++ autotools project to not use rpath?

Tags: c++, linux, autotools, rpath

I have a large autotools project that includes several executables and shared libraries.  The main executable has a RPATH embedded that causes problems later if I want to override with LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Is there a way to tell autotools (via ./configure or otherwise) to NOT embed this rpath?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If not, try setting `LD_RUN_PATH` to an empty value, or take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724365/automake-and-custom-rpath).

Comment: Empty `LD_RUN_PATH` did not work for me, though an `export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/other/path/to/lib ${LDFLAGS:-}"` before compilation seems to have overridden it. It doesn't seem like the best solution though (shouldn't there be a flag passed to libtool to stop it auto-rpathing?)

Comment: `chrpath` utility is the droid you are looking for.